# Compiler generates a call to NULL?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

I have been compiling a C++ (64bit) program and got a SIGSEGV because of a NULL pointer when using gcc. Originally I implemented it with VS 2010, but the code itself is not really compiler dependent and uses only stl and works fine in VS.

When I compiled it with gcc I found this part where there is a call with a NULL pointer.

All the involved objects are `std::string` so this should be save anyway.

```
void Filename::updatePath(void)
{
    size_t len = mBasePath.size();
    if(len > 0)
    {
        len--;
        if(mBasePath[len] != mDelimiter)
            mBasePath += mDelimiter;
    }

    mOpenPath = mBasePath + mFilename;
}
```

The generated assembly

```
107                                             mBasePath += mDelimiter;
0000000000403ac4: 0x00000000488b45d0   mov -0x30(%rbp),%rax
0000000000403ac8: 0x000000000fb64020   movzbl 0x20(%rax),%eax
0000000000403acc: 0x00000000000fbec0   movsbl %al,%eax
0000000000403acf: 0x00000000488b55d0   mov -0x30(%rbp),%rdx
0000000000403ad3: 0x00000000488d4a08   lea 0x8(%rdx),%rcx
0000000000403ad7: 0x00000000000089c2   mov %eax,%edx
0000000000403ad9: 0x000000e8da3e0200   callq 0x4279b8 <_ZNSspLEc>
110                                     mOpenPath = mBasePath + mFilename;
0000000000403ade: 0x00000000488b45d0   mov -0x30(%rbp),%rax
0000000000403ae2: 0x00000000488d4810   lea 0x10(%rax),%rcx
0000000000403ae6: 0x00000000488b45d0   mov -0x30(%rbp),%rax
0000000000403aea: 0x00000000488d5008   lea 0x8(%rax),%rdx
0000000000403aee: 0x00000000488d45a0   lea -0x60(%rbp),%rax
0000000000403af2: 0x00000000004989c8   mov %rcx,%r8
0000000000403af5: 0x00000000004889c1   mov %rax,%rcx
0000000000403af8: 0x000000e803c5bfff   callq 0x0
0000000000403afd: 0x00000000488b45d0   mov -0x30(%rbp),%rax
0000000000403b01: 0x00000000488d4818   lea 0x18(%rax),%rcx
0000000000403b05: 0x00000000488d45a0   lea -0x60(%rbp),%rax
0000000000403b09: 0x00000000004889c2   mov %rax,%rdx
0000000000403b0c: 0x000000e8173c0200   callq 0x427728 <_ZNSsaSEOSs>
```

So can anybody explain what goes wrong here? The code is in a static library which is linked to the executable. I'v been using the `-flto` option but I've done this before, so I don't really see where this could come from.

Do I need to upgrade to a new gcc version?

> gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2

Comment: How did you get the assembly listing? Maybe using `objdump` and forgot to add `-r` option to see relocations?

Comment: The output is from the eclipse disassembly window in gdb

Comment: Could you add the machine code bytes for the call instruction too please?

Comment: I added the opcodes as shown from eclipse. I also added additional code for better context

Comment: I used the function shown above to generate assembly from gcc, and nowhere I see a callq to 0x0. In fact, it is very different from shown fragment.

Comment: Coimpile with `g++ -O -fverbose-asm -S` your C++ code in `foo.cc` then look inside the generated `foo.s` file

Comment: @SergeyA, that's the problem. I dont't see why it should generate this.

Comment: How can I do this from cmake?

Comment: Thanks for the machine code, that is indeed a call to `0`. Just wanted to verify it's not some disassembler problem.

Comment: It would seem that's the call for `operator+` [based on process of elimination] for the `mBasePath + mFilename`. I can't explain why other than "probably a compiler bug".

Comment: Great. So I guess I have to update gcc. I have compiled a pretty big project of mine as well, but haven't seen such a problem before.

Comment: Compiler bug in GCC 4.9.2? In simple operator+ of two strings? Find it really hard to believe.

Comment: I don't think this is a compiler bug.  Simple usage of `std::string` should not be causing such an error, else thousands of programmers using GCC would have reported it.  More than likely, your `FileName` object is corrupted / invalid, and issuing calls to member functions is undefined behavior, or some other memory corruption issue.

Comment: Totally agree with @PaulMcKenzie. I strongl recommend santizing the application (with fsanitize) or valgrinding it.

Comment: It can not really be a runtime problem since the code already has the `call 0` in it. Not sure how valgrind would help. @Devolus do you have the object and library files? Can you check the appropriate ones with `objdump -dr`?

Comment: @Jester, I created the dump with objdump -dr but how can I find the code?

Comment: Compiler can put calls to 0 (or do other stuff) if it sees the program exhibits undefined behaviour. GCC is known for that.

Comment: Once again, where is your [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)??

Comment: You can search for the name of the function, but it's possibly the mangled version which should be `_ZN8Filename10updatePathEv` but you can just search for `updatePath`.

Comment: I don't really understand it but I recompiled now everything again, and it seems to be gone. Only difference is that I put the '-O'  and '-save-temps' flags in, because recompiling several times was the first thing I tried before as well. The code now works, as expected.

Comment: completely agree with LRIO here. You need to post a minimal complete verifiable example so we can point out your logic error. It won't be a compiler problem. it'll be something you wrote and just luckily worked with the microsoft compiler.

Comment: @Devolus, this adds weight to the assumption that your program has undefined behaviour in it. -O inhibits exploting undefined behavior.

Comment: @SergeyA, how should "undefined behaviour" cause a NULL call in the object code???

Comment: @Devolus, easily. If compiler can prove that the code can only reach this point due to undefined behavior, it might use this part for something else. Like a null call.

Comment: @SergeyA, ok , so I will check the code and the warnings and see if I find something. I know that VS is quite different and normally I use gcc only, but in this case I can't... Never heard this before that the compiler puts something like this in the code though.

Comment: @Devolus  See this:  http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213  Undefined behavior can affect what the optimizer does with your code.

Comment: @Devolus, try -fsanitize=undefined as an argument to both compiler and linker. It might (just might!) catch something.

Comment: Anything other than making a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is just a waste of time